# reading properties file in jsp using annotation spring 4

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-annotations, spring-4

I need to do this, with annotation, withouth using xml file.

```
< bean id="placeholderConfig"       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
        < property name="locations" >
            < list >
                < value >app.properties< / value >
            < / list >
        < / property >
< / bean >
```

And I need to call my property values in my jsp like `${test.name}` (where test.name is configured in app.properties)

Now I do this

```
@PropertySource(value="app.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
...
@Bean(name="placeholderConfig")
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer(){
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer cfg = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        cfg.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("app.properties"));
        cfg.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return cfg;
    }
```

In this way i can access whith

```
@Value("${test.name}")
    String name; //contain value of test.name configured in app.properties
```

But if i do ${test.name} in my jsp, this is not read.
To let jsp read the value I have to do (in my java class)

```
@Value("${test.name}")
    String name;
...
model.addObject("name", name);
```

There is a way to access directly to my property from my jsp, whit `${test.name}` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way.
I put this code in my java page, with my bean declarations

```
@Bean(name="messageSource")
    public static ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messareSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/app");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Put file `app_it_IT.properties` in `WEB-INF` folder

```
test.name = test
```

Finally I use this code in jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<spring:message code="test.name" var="propName"/ >
${propName}
```